# What is the Best Practice Setup for Azure Traffic Monitor?

Tags: azure

We have a client that we have setup two webservers running about a dozen different websites spread over each webserver for each site (so site 1 is running on both webservers, site 2 is running on both ect).

We want to setup load balancing (presumably with Traffic Manager) so that it will spread the load and monitor the sites availability across both the web servers per site and not per virtual machine like the regular Azure load balanced sets do.

It seems that traffic manager might be able to do this but we don't know how it works and the documentation is not clear to us about if we can setup the TM per website and not per web server (as we understand it).

Can we setup any load balancing in Azure that will monitor the website itself and not the virtual machine? Because we want to run multiple sites on these two web servers, how do we setup TM do allow this to happen? Do we make a new TM service for each website?

thanks in advance.

UPDATE: do we even need to setup the regular load balancing set at all? Can I not just create a TM and click on the cloud services of each of the web servers and then add the port and relative path to one of the websites? and just repeat this for each website on the two servers? would that be how it should be setup?
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was custom end points from traffic manager. This will allow Azure to be able to monitor the service for each service or website on a web server within Azure.

Answer (score 1):

The available endpoints you can define in your Traffic Manager definition is only as granular as your cloud service URLs.  So, the quick answer to your question is no.

You may want to look into using Application Request Routing in front of your two servers instead.  It does introduce additional server(s) in your configuration but will give you a way to load balance across the sites.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Rick, but I'm not sure if I understand your recommendation. I need to use traffic monitor for load balancing several websites on two web servers. I wanted to know if this was possible and if I had to setup a separate TM service per website? and if will know when a website is offline on one of the servers and still drive traffic to the other website running on the other webserver? (while still monitoring the other websites running on both web servers)